# Why does the RPM (revolutions per minute) fall drastically when I use the windshield washer?

Tags: ford, rpm

I have a Ford Fiesta 2013 model and when I use the windshield washer the RPM falls drastically, it's almost like the car is braking by itself. Does anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: Is that just when spraying water on the glass, or when the wiper arms are moving?

Comment: Hi, when spraying water on the windshield.

Comment: Does this happen when you are idling, or at highway speeds? If you turn on other electrical loads (wipers, AC fan to maximum, headlights on bright) do you also have an RPM drop?

Comment: It happens at idling and highway speeds. Only when spraying water with the wipers to clean the windshield, never with other electrical loads.

Comment: There will likely be a fuse and relay for the washers.  You could remove them individually and see whether the symptoms persist when attempting to use the washers.  Then report back.

Comment: When you check the fuse make sure it's the right Amperage as per the owner's manual.